# How to replace Nan and infinity value with 0 in RDLC report ? And how to round up double value to 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

Hi i'm using rdlc for the report. And i get the Nan and infinity values from list, how can i remove those with 0,
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use bellow Expression

```
  =IIF(Single.IsNAN(  Value   ) or Single.IsInfinity(  Value  ), 0, Round(   Value  ,3) )
```